# Use TSQL to select value B if A is not found

Tags: sql, t-sql

We have an address table where the addresses for an account are marked Primary or Shipping.

We want to select the Shipping address unless there is no shipping address, in which case we want the Primary address.

Whats the best approach using TSQL on SqlServer 2005?

In the below sample, querying for ID 1 or 2 should return the S record. Querying for ID 2 should return the P record.

Note there are other possible address types that should be ignored.

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE(
 ID int,
 AddressType CHAR
)

INSERT INTO @tmp (ID,addresstype) VALUES (1,'P')
INSERT INTO @tmp (ID,addresstype) VALUES (1,'S')
INSERT INTO @tmp (ID,addresstype) VALUES (2,'P')
INSERT INTO @tmp (ID,addresstype) VALUES (2,'A')

SELECT * from @tmp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nasty but it works:

```
 select  distinct t1.id,coalesce (t2.addresstype, t3.addresstype)
 from @tmp t1
 left join @tmp t2 on t1.id = t2.id and  t2.addresstype = 'S'
 left join @tmp t3 on t1.id = t3.id and t3.addresstype = 'P' 
 where t1.addresstype  in ('P', 'S')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fancy code, just rely on `S` > `P` in a set limited to P and S

```
SELECT
    ID, MAX(AddressType)
FROM
    @tmp
WHERE 
    AddressType IN ('P', 'S')
GROUP BY
    ID
```

You can use ROW_NUMBER or a UNION or a derived table too.

If you want for one ID only, then TOP is easier

```
SELECT TOP 1
    ID, AddressType
FROM
    @tmp
WHERE 
    AddressType IN ('P', 'S')
    AND
    ID = 2  --1
ORDER BY
    AddressType DESC
```

It depends on your usage: one ID or many IDs in one query

Comment: wouldn't that fail if there is an addresstype of X, for instance?

Comment: @vlad: Question says "Note there are other possible address types that should be ignored." So we have to assume one of S or P exists otherwise the question is void

Comment: We thought of that but if a new address type was added between S and P it would break it.

Comment: @Kenoyer130: hence the filter to `AddressType IN ('P', 'S')` so you only have these 2 values in the aggregate. This satsifies your *there are other possible address types that should be ignored* bit

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the original question, and was thinking it should NOT be ignored.

Comment: This was a good response, I just didn't like depending on the sort order in case in the future we had to add a third type.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to choose between P or S

Select Top 1 * from @tmp Where AddressType In( 'P', 'S') And ID = @id Order By AddressType Desc

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for **COALESCE**? It returns the first non-null expression among its arguments.

For example, `SELECT COALESCE(ShippingAddress, PrimaryAddress) FROM tableName`....
retrieves `ShippingAddress` if it is not `NULL`, and if `ShippingAddress` is `NULL`, it returns `PrimaryAddress`, unless `PrimaryAddress` is also `NULL`, in which case it just returns `NULL`.

Here is an [example page](http://www.sqlbook.com/SQL/SQL-Coalesce-28.aspx) that might be helpful. And the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx).

Comment: This assume 2 columns or a self join

Comment: You can put as many columns as you want in the COALESCE arguments.

Comment: I should have said "give us an example" rather then mentioning COALESCE without any context or example. I do have some *slight* clue about SQL... -1 for lack of explanation or example of usage

Comment: @gbn I am mystified by your comment and downvote. The SQL after the words "For example," is my example based on some assumed table containing addresses, not the temp table above, which does not contain addresses and which may not be necessary to accomplish the questioner's objective. The accepted answer also uses COALESCE.

Comment: There is **one** column in the table. How does that work with COALESCE? Your example is meaningless. The accepted answer uses a *self join* which I mentioned in my first comment here.